# TypeScript non-null assertion operator does not work

Tags: typescript, non-nullable

I have a type with a conditional property (in this case 'b')

```
type tp1 = {a: string, b?: Array<number>};
```

I create an object of this type, where conditional properties are present

```
const a: tp1 = {a: '10', b: [1,2,3]};
```

I'm trying to log and check how they work and non-null assertion operator, and get error in second log, but why?
can someone explain this to me?
and how to remove this error if I know exactly which object will come? (not '@ts-ignore')
[ts playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMYIxQLxQN4EMBcUDOwBOAlgHYDmANFAEYD8WAgnnmiADxECuAtpRHgHwBfANwAoEQGMA9kVxRMMeElTyA5HAAMKipSwBtOGQBMZAMwBdYWKkzJAGwgA6W5JIAKFcAiznJKFrkAhA6UAJSi1th2jj7unt4ufhRoQZS6hmZhQA)

```
console.log('1st test log ', a!.b); // everything is fine
console.log('2nd test log ', a!.b[2]); // Object is possibly 'undefined'
```

Comment: That isn't how `!` works. You use it *right after* the nullable value. In this case, it's `a.b`, so it would look like `a.b![2]`.

Comment: It's not `a` that's possibly-undefined, it's `a.b`. So you use `!` on `a.b`: `a.b![2]` [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMYIxQLxQN4EMBcUDOwBOAlgHYDmANFAEYD8WAgnnmiADxECuAtpRHgHwBfANwAoEQGMA9kVxRMMeElTyA5HAAMKipSwBtOGQBMZAMwBdYWKkzJAGwgA6W5JIAKFcAiznJKFrkOlACUotbYdo4+7p7eLn4UaIEAhLqGZiFAA).

Comment: That said, however, the `!` (like all type assertions) is best avoided wherever possible. Often, when you "know" it'll be fine, that's where the gotcha happens. Most of the time, I prefer calling a [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) with a nice clear error when the assertion is wrong: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3XnLW).